# Is PHP ArgumentCountError server specific?

Tags: php, parameter-passing

I am facing very weird problem since last two days, I have two different servers one is windows(php v5.3) and second is linux(php v7.1 ngnix). I have a project(written by someone) which is already running on windows server, now I have to move this project on linux server (with no code change). My issue, There is a login function -

```
Function userAuthentication($username,$password,$locationId,$url,$source)
{
....
}
```

And It is calling as (On windows server)

```
userAuthentication($username, $password,'',$url) ;
```

I know parameters are mismatched in this case but as I tested, this code is actually giving me result and working fine on windows but that same code is giving me obvious error on Linux server-

> ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function
>   Authentication::userAuthentication(), 4 passed in

It can be resolve by changing that code but I don't want (can to be many function with same error).
I already googled but not found anything. I am very curious to know Why this is not happening on windows. Is that ArgumentCountError server specific or windows server not taking it as critical as linux, or php version issue or any other config.? what I suppose to fix to resolve this issue.?

Anyone have any idea about that please help me out, Thanks

Comment: And of course it's veeery hard to google, right? http://php.net/manual/en/class.argumentcounterror.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Admincategory::deletecategory(),](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108428/fatal-error-uncaught-argumentcounterror-too-few-arguments-to-function-admincat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference isn't in the Environment (windows vs. linux) rather the PHP version.

As you can see in the migration from PHP 7.0 to 7.1 (link: http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php)

**Throw on passing too few function arguments**

> Previously, a warning would be emitted for invoking user-defined
>   functions with too few arguments. Now, this warning has been promoted
>   to an Error exception. This change only applies to user-defined
>   functions, not internal functions. For example:

```
<?php
function test($param){}
test();
```

The above example will output something similar to:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
>   function test(), 0 passed in %s on line %d and exactly 1 expected in
>   %s:%d

**How to solve it?**

You'll have to define all the parameters in the function. It might be "uncomfortable" but it's a better practice as a developer. Don't be lazy regarding this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Now i have so much work as you suggested. :P

Answer (score 1):

This has everything to do with the newer PHP versions that are (as they should) be more strict about calling. If you want this to work again make the additional parameters optional by giving them default values.

You should update to 7.x locally to prevent this sort of issues.

Like:

```
Function userAuthentication($username,$password,$locationId,$url,$source = '')
```